# Aggregate XML Nodes based on condition

Tags: xml, xslt

I have quite a simple task at hand, which i'm unable to solve in XSLT. I have to aggregate XML Nodes based on adjoining Timestamps (ns1:ValidUntil = ns1:ValidFrom) and equal Names (ns1:Name).

I have played around with recursive templates and xpath axis navigation (preceding-sibling/following-sibling), but i'm unable to solve the issue at hand.

Would be really happy for any suggestions.

Input XML:

```
<ns1:Zone>
    <ns1:ID>xyz</ns1:ID>
    <ns1:Direction>abc</ns1:Direction>

    <ns1:Elem>
        <ns1:Name>Z01</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:ValidFrom>2013-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidFrom>
        <ns1:ValidUntil>2014-01-01T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidUntil>
    </ns1:Elem>

    <ns1:Elem>
        <ns1:Name>Z01</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:ValidFrom>2016-01-13T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidFrom>
        <ns1:ValidUntil>2018-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidUntil>
    </ns1:Elem>

    <ns1:Elem>
        <ns1:Name>Z02</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:ValidFrom>2014-01-13T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidFrom>
        <ns1:ValidUntil>2014-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidUntil>
    </ns1:Elem>
    <ns1:Elem>
        <ns1:Name>Z02</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:ValidFrom>2014-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidFrom>
        <ns1:ValidUntil>2015-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidUntil>
    </ns1:Elem>

    <ns1:Elem>
        <ns1:Name>Z03</ns1:Name>
        <ns1:ValidFrom>2016-01-13T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidFrom>
        <ns1:ValidUntil>2016-11-20T06:00:00.000+01:00</ns1:ValidUntil>
    </ns1:Elem>
</ns1:Zone>
```

Comment: Can you explain words in what way you want to aggregate the data? As you seem to be using XSLT 2.0 I think doing `<xsl:for-each-group select="//ns1:Elem" group-by="ns1:Name">...</xsl:for-each-group>` helps but I am not sure how you want to aggregate those dateTime values.

Comment: I want to combine all xml elements "ns1:Elem", which have the same name (that would work with for-each-group) AND which have the same value in ValidUntil and ValidFrom (in the above example ns1:Elem/ns1:Name "Z01" occurs three times, but has adjoining dates -> thus it has to be put into a single element (with the ValidFrom Timestamp from the first element and the ValidTo from the last element in the set)). You can easily see, what i mean in the input/output xml posted, if you don't understand my explanation (which could be better i guess)

Comment: I think I now understand your requirements, at least for the sample you have posted. What happens with `ns1:Elem` that don't fit into a date/time range? And do the elements need to be adjacent in the input sample to group them, as they are in the sample? Or can an element to be grouped also appear later on, separated by elements of another name and/or date/time range?

Comment: ns1:Elem, that don't fit into a date/time range have to be added to the output aswell..  Even, if they occur within a group (e.g. Z01/Z02/Z03) Guess this is why the below solution with min()/max() will not work..

Comment: I have changed the code to not simply group on name but to group adjacent elements of the same name and the date/time sequence, try that edited code with your data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can group as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://example.com/ns1"
  xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/ns1"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Zone">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="* except Elem"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="Elem" group-adjacent="Name">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-adjacent="ValidUntil = following-sibling::Elem[1]/ValidFrom or ValidFrom = preceding-sibling::Elem[1]/ValidUntil">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="ValidFrom, current-group()[last()]/ValidUntil"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Found one problem: If two elements with non - overlapping dates are found within a "name group" the algorithm fails to group correctly. Three elements (two overlapping, one not overlapping) are processed correctly.. Any idea, what causes this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question with a minimal but complete input sample producing that problem, then it is easier to see where the suggested approach fails and hopefully we can fix it.

Comment: @f00f1ght3r, I have extended the code, it should cover the input samples you have shown so far.

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same code.. Guess i learned a lot about for-each-group today :) Thank you very much, Martin :)